# Mixed effect linear regression model output interpretation

Tags: r, linear-model, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I just fitted the following linear mixed effects model:

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
 Formula: price ~ variable + (1 | product)
    Data: podzbior

       AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 130840.14 130868.85 -65416.07 130832.14      9674 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
 -6.2824 -0.3099 -0.0547  0.2201 12.4291 

Random effects:
 Groups           Name     Variance Std.Dev.
 product         (Intercept) 427375   653.7   
 Residual                     25930   161.0   
 Number of obs: 9678, groups: product, 1222

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error  t value
 (Intercept)     9.362e+02  1.899e+01    49.29
  variable      -7.521e-04  1.171e-04    -6.42

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
              (Intr)
  variable    -0.050
```

That was output from `summary(lmerModel)`, after the run of `lmer` I got this warning:

```
Warning:
  In checkScaleX(X, ctrl = control) :
  Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
```

Q1 Predictor variable is numeric from 0 to something like 100k, how It should be scaled?

Random effects with confidence intervals chart for this model looks like this, is it OK?:

[image]

I am pretty sure residuals are not OK. What should I do in this case?

[image]

How can I go deeper with this model diagnostic, besides checking p-values?

Comment: This QQ-plot strongly suggests you have a heavy-tailed distribution. The "most vanilla" rescaling would be to first try to make your data zero-meaned and having std.deviation of 1; this is not a final solution just a first step. Try it and see if your model behaves better.

Comment: Well, I have used scale() to make predictor variable with mean equal 0 and sd equal 0 - qqplot still looks the same, any other ideas for rescalling?

Comment: OK, so something more informed might be helpful. What is `variable`? Is is reasonable to take the `sqrt` of it? To `log` it? To do something like `I(variable/1e6)` maybe? Try to think easily interpretable transformations before doing something *heavy-handed* like a Box-Cox.

Comment: Box-Cox gave me lambda close to 0 so this mean log transformation, still nothing close to normality in qqplots of residuals

Comment: Try then robust regression methods. In particular the functionality offered by the packages `lqmm` and `robustlmm` might can handy...

Comment: @usεr11852 I don't think that standardisation ($\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$) would change the distribution of the residuals. It just change the scale but not the shape.

Answer (score 1):

Your QQ-plot shows heavy tails which suggests that your data/observations are not coming from a normal distribution. While rescaling might still be relevant here, what you really need to do is to first try and transform your dependent variables "price" (e.g., to log(price)) to make your observations closer to normal. Otherwise, you cannot trust your model fit and errors.

You might want to look at the BoxCox transformations to understand which transformation is appropriate for your data.

Otherwise you might want to consider non-linear mixed models that better fit your model.